# How can I reverse lookup multiple DNS names using Python and Scapy from a traceroute?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, dns, scapy

I've got a program using Python and the [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) library that does a traceroute and graphs the results. Looks great, but all the nodes are just IP addresses. I'd love to reverse DNS lookup the IP addresses that are part of the results.

```
from scapy.all import *

# List of websites to trace
site_list = ["google.com"]

# This creates the trace using ICMP packets
# and outputs the text result to the screen
res, unans = traceroute(site_list, maxttl=30, l4=ICMP())

# Create a graph in SVG format
res.graph(target="> traceroute_scapy.svg", type="svg")
```

Where I have `ICMP()` I  think I need to do something like `ICMP()/DNS()` but I'm not sure exactly what is needed there.

(Side note, the graph doesn't work with the current 2.4.2 Scapy, because of the Autonomous System (ASN) lookup. You need to use the dev version until they release the next Scapy version.)

[image]

Comment: "I'd love to reverse DNS lookup the IP addresses that are part of the results." So you need a DNS library to do that. look at `dnspython` for example. DNS and ICMP have nothing to do between each other. Also, whatever you are doing, ICMP is usually a bad choice for network troubleshooting. If you need to monitor something/trace paths, you need to do it using the protocol related to what you test. For HTTP/HTTPs, do a TCP open to port 80/443, for SMTP to port 25, etc.

Comment: The scapy library can do reverse DNS lookup. I can easily do it with one IP, not sure how to do it with a list. In my case I showed ICMP because a) it does a better traceroute through one of the routers than TCP, and b) it shows the level-4 parameter which I think is what needs to be expanded to do a reverse DNS lookup. I'd like it to a reverse lookup similar to the default traceroute and tracert on Windows/Linux/Mac.